# How to create exam grading program in c++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, functional-programming

I try to help friend to finish his exam to create this exam grading program in C++ but all try failed to compile this program. Can you help me?
Every try always gets "fatal error" and "No such file or directory
compilation terminated." So far we try to compile it with online compiler.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <iostream.h>
# include <conio.h>

main()
{
   char nama[20],*Grade;
   float nk,nt,nu,nmk,nmt,nmu,na;
   cout<<"Program Hitung Nilai Akhir Siswa"<<endl<<endl;
   cout<<"   Masukkan Nama Siswa : ";gets(nama);
   cout<<"   Nilai Keaktifan     : ";cin>>nk;
   cout<<"   Nilai Tugas         : ";cin>>nt;
   cout<<"   Nilai Ujian         : ";cin>>nu;
   nmk=nk*0.2;
   nmt=nt*0.3;
   nmu=nu*0.5;
   na=nmk+nmt+nmu;
   if(na>=80)a
   {
      Grade="A";
   }
   else if(na>=90)
   {
      Grade="B";
   }
   else if(na>=80)
   {
      Grade="C";
   }
   else if(na>=70)
   {
      Grade="D";
   }
   else
   {
      Grade="E";
   }
   cout<<endl;
   cout<<"     Siswa Yang Bernama "<<nama<<endl;
   cout<<"     Dengan nilai presentase yang dihasilkan"<<endl;
   cout<<"     Nilai Murni Keaktifan x 20%    : "<<nmk<<endl;
   cout<<"     Nilai Murni Tugas     x 30%    : "<<nmt<<endl;
   cout<<"     Nilai Murni Ujian     x 50%    : "<<nmu<<endl;
   cout<<"     Memperoleh Nilai Akhir Sebesar : "<<na<<endl;
   cout<<"     Grade yang di dapat            : "<<Grade<<endl;
   getch();
}
```

Comment: An online compiler will not recognize non-standard headers that were used in c++ compilers 20+ years ago. Get rid of `# include <iostream.h>` and `# include <conio.h>`. Use `#include <iostream>` instead of `# include <iostream.h>`

Comment: you need to add `using namespace std` or `std::` infront or all std functions

Comment: Also `char *Grade` and then `Grade = "A"` will not work

Comment: also `char * Grade` -> `char Grade` and then `Grade='A'` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most online compilers use the latest C++ standards. They most likely don't support old style C++ programs.

Things you can change to get going...

**`#include` lines**

Instead of

```
 # include <stdio.h>
 # include <iostream.h>
```

Use

```
 # include <cstdio>
 # include <iostream>
```

**Don't use non-standard header**

Remove

```
 # include <conio.h>
```

**`cin` and `cout` are in `std` namespace**

Change all usages of `cin` by `std::cin` and all usages of `cout` by `std::cout`. You can also use

```
using namespace std;
```

to avoid having to use `std::cin` and `std::cout`. However, don't use this mechanism everywhere to avoid having to type the additional `std::`.

**Don't use `gets`**

Use of `gets` is a known source of security vulnerabilities. Don't use it.
Replace its usage by `fgets`.

Instead of

```
   cout<<"   Masukkan Nama Siswa : ";gets(nama);
```

you could use

```
   cout<<"   Masukkan Nama Siswa : ";
   fgets(nama, sizeof(nama), stdin);
```

However, that is not good either since you are mixing use of `stdin` and `cin` to get user input. Either stick to the use of functions from `stdio.h`or use `cin` to get user input. You can use:

```
   cout<<"   Masukkan Nama Siswa : ";
   cin.get(nama, sizeof(nama));
```

**Use `std::string` instead of `char*` to hold strings**

Change

```
   char nama[20],*Grade;
```

to

```
   char nama[20];
   std::string Grade;
```

**Don't use non-standard functions**

Remove the line

```
   getch();
```